# Delegate is not visible in the QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have created a class `customDelegate` (inherits `QItemDelegate`) in my Qt application and I created `setEditor()` function.But the delegate is not visible in the `QTableView`, until I click on the row.

The `customDelegate` class has a `QPushButton` and a `QLabel`.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: There is no `QItemDelegate::setEditor` function. What did you mean?

Comment: please, post your delegate's code